# How to play Mortal Kombat 1, 2 and 3 on Windows 7?

Tags: pc, backwards-compatibility, mortal-kombat-1992, mortal-kombat-2, mortal-kombat-3

How do I install and play Mortal Kombat 1, 2 and 3 on Windows 7 64-bit?

Comment: its too bad mortal kombat kollection is no longer available for purchase on steam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mortal Kombat 1, 2 and 3's arcade versions can be played using [MAME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAME) (an arcade game system emulator). Their console versions can be played using console emulators; the emulator will depend on which console version you want to play, e.g. [Kega Fusion](http://www.carpeludum.com/kega-fusion/) (Sega Genesis / Mega Drive), [Snes9x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snes9x) (SNES), [ePSXe](http://www.epsxe.com/) (PlayStation).

As for the game itself, you'll need to acquire a copy of its [ROM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROM_image) that the emulator will then run.

Comment: In fact, you can play them all with MAME. No need of another emulator.

Comment: @Fabián MAME can only play the arcade versions.

Comment: What's the difference between playing them all in MAME, and playing them with each different emulator?

Comment: @Fabián The console versions are not exactly the same as their arcade versions. See their respective Wikipedia articles for the details. I'm trying to give OP and anyone with a similar question, information on how to play the different versions of the games.

Comment: an old question, but it might be worth noting that in some cases, you can use an original copy of the game through an emulator (for example, an original PS1 game will run through the ePSXe emulator). This is still covered in needing the "ROM", but future users may not immediately realise that the game, itself, is a form of ROM.

Answer (score 2):

You can play them using [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/)

Answer (score 2):

I have win 7 64-bit and mortal kombat trilogy didn't setup on win 7 and showed this error: the version of the file is not compatible with the version of windows you'er running.

I setup the game on an Windows XP (by means of virtual pc) and after setup I copied all the installation files and transferred them into my windows 7 64-bit and the game runs perfectly, just like old times!

The problem is about the installer- not the game. If you use a compatible OS such as Windows XP to install the game and copy the files after setup the game runs on win 7 64-bit with no problem!